# ColdBox's ApplicationHelper.cfm filepath being found in PCI scan

Tags: coldfusion, pci-compliance, coldbox

I have an application that is undergoing a PCI scan.  The scan is tripping up on a ColdBox route that has values appended afterwards that don't make sense.  As an example, it is `www.mydomain.com/route/non-coldbox-directory/non-coldbox-directory/page.cfm`

The page loads to `www.mydomain.com/route/` with extra stuff in the URL that's not being used.

The PCI scan is returning a `Reference to Windows file path is present in HTML`, and it's specifically pointing to a ColdBox helper file `{wwwroot}\includes\helpers\ApplicationHelper.cfm`.  However, in viewing the HTML source of the generated route, `www.mydomain.com/route/`, nothing is there.  What is causing this flag?

This is on a Windows server, running CF 10 and ColdBox 3.X

Comment: Really dumb question. Can you just rename the file to `Applicatiohelper.cfi` ? Disclaimer. I use `*.cfi` for CF files that can only be included and never ran directly

Comment: The only reference I can see in ColdBox regarding this file is in the `Coldbox.cfc` file under the `config` directory, specifically `UDFLibraryFile = "includes/helpers/ApplicationHelper.cfm"`.  Perhaps Coldbox is dumping something out that PCI is picking up but not the browser? How can I check for this?

Comment: You could try to hit the file directly via the URL

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I was being clear:  When I go to the sample URL: `www.mydomain.com/route/non-coldbox-directory/non-coldbox-directory/page.cfm` PCI is stating that a `Reference to Windows file path is present in HTML` and that file is `{wwwroot}\includes\helpers\ApplicationHelper.cfm`.  The generated HTML source has NO reference to that or ANY directory. Running `www.mydomain.com/includes/helpers/applicationHelper.cfm` directly generates an EMTPY HTML document. I cleaned up any error handling and resubmitted for another scan. Perhaps it will clear this time.

Comment: It may have generated an empty HTML document, but it was parsed and it ran. Consider this, could a CF file that generates an empty HTML document be destructive?